# $this_array=array ("this", "and", "this", "and", "th")

Tags: php, arrays

How would i find the length of an element within an array, to make sure each is over 2 characters long.  Using php that is...

ex. $this_array=array ("this", "and", "this", "and", "th")

Comment: You might have to use foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

Looping may be a bit overkill, unless there's more you need to do - filtering is much more effective.

```
<?
$this_array =  array("a", "this", "and", "this", "and", "th");

$this_array = array_filter($this_array, function($val){return strlen($val)>=2;});

print_r($this_array); // Array ( [1] => this [2] => and [3] => this [4] => and [5] => th )
```

Note: This will only work in PHP 5.3+

Comment: Anonymous functions are only available in PHP 5.3 on. It seems like the site you've provided is using PHP 5.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($this_array as $val) {
   $valLength = strlen($val); //gives length 
   if($valLength < 3) {
       //something here, less than 2 char
   } 
}
```

Comment: This should be `< 3` not `< 2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($this_array as $key => $value)
{
    if (strlen($value) < 3)
    {
        echo "{$value} is too short<br />";
    }
}
```

See [foreach](http://php.net/foreach)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($this_array as $value) {
   $strlen = strlen($value);
   if($strlen <= 2)
   {
     echo '$value is '.$strlen.' characters long<br />';   
     // do something with it
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this_array=array ("aa", "bb", "cc", "asd", "aa");    



function lengthCheck($v, $w)
    {
     global $lengthOK;
       $len=  strlen($w);
       if($len<3)
       {
        $lengthOK=false;
       }
        return $lengthOK;
    }


    $lengthOK=true;// set everytime when you call "lengthCheck"
    $b = array_reduce($this_array, "lengthCheck");

    var_dump($b);
```

$b will have true/flase. i.e. TRUE if all elements have length 3 or more, false otherwise.